# How to run a python script in IDLE using CMD prompt

Tags: python, python-idle

I am wondering if there is a way to open a python script in IDLE run mode, (the equivalent of opening it with idle.exe {path} and pressing F5) or set it up so that if a .py file is open with IDLE it automatically runs it.

```
#Opens without IDLE GUI
python {path}
#Opens in IDLE, but in editor mode
@ECHO OFF
idle.exe {path_to_idle}
```

Comment: do you mean execute the `.py` file? why doesn't `python script_name.py` not work?

Comment: It works fine, I just personally prefer the GUI of the IDLE, and I plan to write a package for ATOM to execute the command in IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Running script.py in idle
idle.exe -r script.py
```

You might consider using:

```
# Inspect interactively after running script (see "python --help" from cmd)
python -i script.py
```